# CSS inside my PHP file

Tags: php, css, variables, external

Okay, so I've been able to define the standard text color according to a database value by using this code:

```
<?php

echo '<div style="color: ' . $result->properties->fcolor . ';';<br />
echo 'background: ' . $result->properties->bgcolor;<br />
echo '">MY CONTENT</div>'

?>
```

The color that's set by

```
$results->properties->fcolor
```

works nicely, except for `a:link`, `a:hover`, `a:visited`, and `a:active`.  Because it's only defining "color", the browsers default to their own link colors.

My users choose from a selection of background and font colors and Chrome's default blue link color doesn't exactly work with a dark purple background... Is it possible to set up a

```
<style type=text/css>
```

inside of my PHP file and have it reference the

```
$result->properties->fcolor
```

value that the normal part of the script pulls from my database?

This is my first big site so I'm not positive about anything but I vaguely remember enabling PHP in my external CSS file using .htaccess and it didn't successfully pull in the value of

```
$result->properties->fcolor
```

as far as I could tell.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance - amazing community here! :)

Comment: By the way, this behaviour has nothing to do with php. You can just use static html file with styles to see how browser behaves and how browser styles (firebug/chrome inspector is even better, you can modify the values on the fly). The php just assembles those html/css files.

Comment: @ibu No, I added that so it would be easier to read (echoes get confusing easily unless there are line breaks)...

Comment: @Janis Veinbergs I'm not positive I understand what you're trying to say, but if I'm hearing you right, I already know that :) The issue is a matter of putting the value of $result->properties->fcolor (which is far from static) into a CSS file (internal or external).  Let me know if I'm just misunderstanding you :)

Comment: @tylerl - I just wanted to know if your page style doesn't look like it should, you can debug it using static html/css files until you get desired style for your page. From there, you know what values and where $result->properties->fcolor must be set.

Comment: @Janis Veinbergs Oh, thanks :)  Life is a lot easier with Chrome's inspector :)  Seeing an issue now where the amount of whitespace below my footer mimics the height of the content inside my <div> tags and Chrome isn't showing where the problem is!  Now I don't know what to do :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF I'm you, I would create external css for links just to define rules not color.

for example if your links are inside div, what you can do is just define to use color of div

```
div a { color: inherit; }
div a:HOVER { color: inherit; }
```

so when you define your color to div through php logic your links inside div will inherit that color.

If you experience any problems with this add important to property so color of div will be used

```
div a {color: inherit !important; }
```

Comment: Uh-oh... I just learned the hard way that IE6 and IE7 don't support inherited colors!  Most of my users are on the lower end of computer spectrum so I need IE6/7 to be supported as much as possible :(  Adding `important!` didn't make a difference, so how else do I tell IE to ignore its local values for link colors?  Or is it actually possible to reference `$result->properties->fcolor` in internal or external CSS?  Was I just doing it wrong before?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: put the exclamation mark in front of important, not at the end, and set color you want to use :) do not inherit it.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can set you link colors via internal css

```
<style type="text/css">
a:link { color:#f00;}
a:visited { color : }
a:hover {}
a:active { }
</style>
```

Note:
1 orders are very important .
2 use hex value instead of color name.

Comment: I tried that, replacing '#f00' with '<?php echo $result->properties->fcolor ?>', and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried using " instead of ' and \" instead of "?

```
echo "<div style=\"color: " . $result->properties->fcolor . ";"; 
echo "background: " . $result->properties->bgcolor; 
echo "\">MY CONTENT</div>";
```

And, you seem to be missing a semi colon at your 3rd echo.